# Boolean value in one-to-many DataBase

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, boolean, one-to-many

I'm trying to create a form to assign a seat in various classroom for each lesson.
I created a database with access that contain two table:
Tabel1: Lesson, Day, Hours, Number of seats in that classroom.
Then i created a second table (Tabel2) in one to many relationship with the first: for every lesson it will be the right number of seats (each number represents one seats)and a boolean value (true if the seat is free, false otherwise). I already connected the DB to my project in Visual Studio. 
With the ADD button (and then SAVE) I can assign the parameters of a lesson with the value in the textboxes. Here the code:

```
Private Sub Add_button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Add_button.Click
    Tabel1BindingSource.AddNew()
End Sub

Private Sub Save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Save.Click
    Try
        Tabel1BindingSource.EndEdit()
        Tabel1TableAdapter.Update(Me.DBDataSet.Tabel1)
        MessageBox.Show("ok.")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error.")
    End Try
End Sub
```

The code works correctly.
After I want to create a schema of classroom and a checkbox for each seat checked if the seat is occupied.
My question is: how can I write on the tabel2 the number of seat (from 1 to N according the value in textbox) and the checkstate = 0 for all seats (that means all seats free at the beginning)?

Comment: Are you saying you want to write 'n' records to Table2 (where 'n' = # of seats)?  Your table design can specify the default value for fields (i.e. False for 'checkstate'), or you can specify value in the code. My Visual Studio is so rusty, the gate will not open! But, why not create a 'For i = 1 to NbrSeats' loop that has the code to add to Table2?

Comment: Yes, i want to write 'n' records to Table2 but he must be associated with the ID of the lesson in the two DataBase one-to-many. For the first time (when i create the  "lesson") obviously all seats are "unchecked" that is to say all value on false. After, when sameone want to reserve a seat can check over the seat he want inside the schema of classroom (that is a form i'll create) and reserve the seat. In this case that value in tabel2 will become "true".

Comment: Assume there are 30 seats. When you save the Table1 data, do you want to populate Table2 with 30 records, all set to False? Or do you want to wait until someone uses your form to select a seat, then you add 1 record to Table2? Next, I assume your 'schema' is the same as a 'map or layout' (like airline lets you pick a seat)? Or will it simply be 30 numbered checkboxes that can be checked or unchecked? Are you saving the name or ID of the person in the seat?

Comment: Yes, When I save the Table1 data, i want populate Table2 with 30 records, all set to False refering to the lesson. 
The schema is a type of layout maked of checkbox  with Appearance of a Button. when someone want to reserve a seat must check a button. I do not care to keep track of the name of the person.

Comment: Are you comfortable with how to add a record to Table2? Basically, when you are finished adding the record to Table1, save the seat count and ID, then add the code to repeat adding a row to Table2 'n' times using the 'ID'. Since I'm guessing your classrooms vary the number of seats, you will need to have a form with 30 or 40 'checkboxes'. You can hide the excess (i.e. hide 31-40 of classroom with 30 seats). Have you created the form to assign seats yet?

Comment: you are in right. The better solution is what you said. When someone reserves a seat i add a row related with the lesson.
I'm a beginner. Can you help me with the code?

Comment: I no longer have access to Visual Studio so I can only supply VBA code. Since you say 'The code works correctly', and 'I want to populate with 30 records', the subroutine where you save Table1 is where you need to add code. I will attempt to add an Answer that can be modified / enhanced as we go along. Give me a few minutes to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In your existing subroutine where you add the record for Table1, modify it as follows:

```
Sub Save_Table1()
Dim i As Integer
Dim iSeats as Integer
Dim iID    as Integer   ' Or if a string, dim as a string and name as sID

' Before you insert to Table1 add the following two lines:
iSeats = <your control that contains seat count
iID = <your control that contains the unique key of the record you are adding>

' This is where your existing code to 'Insert or 'Save to Table1 is located

' Add the following to add n Records
For i = 1 to iSeats
    'Add VS code to insert record into Table2 using i as the SeatNbr and iID as the ID key.

Next i
```

Once you have done the above and gotten it to work, you can create your form to be used for seat assignments.